# Dividing double into arrays

Tags: c#

I have an integer array of dimension n, say now n=9.

I would like to initialize it to

```
[0.11,0.11,0.11,0.11,0.11,0.11,0.11,0.11,0.12]
```

Where each entry is 1/n, and take up to two decimals,
and the last entry is the remaining number from 1.

How should I do this easily? Here's what I do now

```
double sumOfn=0;
  for (int i = 0; i < array.Length;i++ )
               {
                   double n;

                   if (i < array.Length-1)
                   {
                       array[i] = Math.Floor((1/(double)  array.Length)*100/100);
                       sumOfn += n;

                   }else
                   {
                       array[i] = 1 - sumOfn;
                   }

}
```

Comment: "Where each entry is 1/n, and take up to two decimals, and the last entry is the remaining number from 1."  Under normal floating point math there is no remainder to a division.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Along the line of Math.Floor((1/n)*100)/100), just to see if there is better way

Comment: What I want to do is partition 1 into n partitions

Comment: Have you tried a `for` loop? That is what I would do.

Comment: Yes, I knew it could be done, just to see is there other more creative way :)

Comment: We can't know if there is a more creative way without knowing your way first.

Comment: Keep in mind that the value of position 1..(n-1) will all be the same.  You don't need to re-calculate them all.  The only item that *might* be different is the item at position n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't constraint a double to a specific precision when you compute a value.

What I would recommend is doing an integer division of 100 per n then divide that value by 100.

The last value can be easily computed by adding the rest of the division to the last element before dividing it by 100.

This is basically an euclidean division as we did in school when we first learned floating point :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this counts as creative.. :)

```
        double[] array = new double[9];
        if (array.Length < 1 || array.Length > 100) throw new InvalidTimeZoneException("lol");
        array = Enumerable.Concat(
            Enumerable.Repeat(100 / array.Length, array.Length - 1),
            new[] { 100 - ((array.Length - 1) * (100 / array.Length)) }
            ).Select(i => i / 100.0).ToArray();
```